# Responsive image/banner that is also expandable written in HTML/CSS/Javascript or w Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I am looking to create an image that is responsive but also expandable. I need to do this all in HTML/CSS and utlize either Javascript or JQuery to make it expandable. I'm able to do either an expandable unit, or a responsive image - but having a hard time combining the two things. Could use some examples or guidance.

So the example scenario would be, on intial page load there is a 924x70 across the page (that is responsive). If you click that unit it expands to 924x250 (this unit also needs to be responsive) - is this even possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think the key thing you're missing here is how to calculate an aspect ratio. Once you've figured that out, you can develop a formulae.

Comment: Could be - would a solution like this work: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/responsive-banner-ads and then just call all that action in via an iframe?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the need for an iFrame, but that's a solution that would definitely help you get going in the right direction.

Comment: `img { width: 100%; height: auto }`

Comment: Yeah probably wouldn't need an iframe - I've tried a couple solutions - but i'm still a bit lost - I think your suggestion about understanding calculating the ratio would help - but I don't quite get it -

Comment: Post some code.  Also why not define a div wrapper, change the size of the wrapper in px and only define one dimension like width of the image as a percentage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use responsive design through media queries to control the initial image size. Then use jquery to adjust the size on click.

Here is a [basic example](http://codepen.io/lukeocom/pen/yltnh) that uses the mouse hover to change the image size. Adjusting the window size will trigger the media queries, but you will need to do this before mouse hover. It should be a straight forward task to adjust this base example to your needs.

basic html

```
<img src="theImage" />
```

media query

```
@media screen and (max-width:300px){    
    img{width:200px;}
}
```

jquery
see [demo](http://codepen.io/lukeocom/pen/yltnh)

hope this helps...